# Paypal SDK problen

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk

Here is my code:

```
if($approved) {

        $payerId = $_GET['PayerID'];

        // Get payment_id from database
        $paymentId = mysql_query("Select payment_id from transactions_paypal WHERE hash = '".$_SESSION['paypal_hash']."'");

        $paymentId = mysql_fetch_array($paymentId);

        $payment = Payment::get($paymentId, $apiContext);

        echo "<pre>";
        var_dump($payment);
        echo "</pre>";
        die();



    }else {
        header('Location: ../paypal/cancelled.php');
    }
```

But I get this errors:

> Notice: Array to string conversion in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\Tipperen\test\PayPal-PHP-SDK\paypal\rest-api-sdk-php\lib\PayPal\Api\Payment.php
>   on line 322

or

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception
>   'PayPal\Exception\PayPalConnectionException' with message 'Got Http
>   response code 404 when accessing
>   https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment/Array.' in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\Tipperen\test\PayPal-PHP-SDK\paypal\rest-api-sdk-php\lib\PayPal\Core\PayPalHttpConnection.php:159
>   Stack trace: #0
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\Tipperen\test\PayPal-PHP-SDK\paypal\rest-api-sdk-php\lib\PayPal\Transport\PayPalRestCall.php(74):
>   PayPal\Core\PayPalHttpConnection->execute('') #1
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\Tipperen\test\PayPal-PHP-SDK\paypal\rest-api-sdk-php\lib\PayPal\Common\PayPalResourceModel.php(103):
>   PayPal\Transport\PayPalRestCall->execute(Array, '/v1/payments/pa...',
>   'GET', '', NULL) #2
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\Tipperen\test\PayPal-PHP-SDK\paypal\rest-api-sdk-php\lib\PayPal\Api\Payment.php(328):
>   PayPal\Common\PayPalResourceModel::executeCall('/v1/payments/pa...',
>   'GET', '', NULL, Object(PayPal\Rest\ApiContext), NULL) #3
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\Tipperen\test\paypal\pay.php(20):
>   PayPal\Api\Payment::get(Array, Object(PayPal\Rest\ApiContext)) in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\Tipperen\test\PayPal-PHP-SDK\paypal\rest-api-sdk-php\lib\PayPal\Core\PayPalHttpConnection.php
>   on line 159

Please help me.

Comment: `$paymentId` is an array, and apparently what you pass as the first parameter into `Payment::get()` should be a string.

Comment: Do you know what the second error is?

Comment: Once fixed, you should be able to make the call. You wont see the second error, as you can see, the 404 error is pointing to https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment/Array. Once Array is fixed with proper PaymentId, you would get something like :https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment/123123123